# MS List view not filtering after list exceeds 5000 items

Tags: list-view

I have a modern MS List that recently hit over 5,000 items.  In anticipation of hitting this threshold, I had created several alternate views knowing the default **All Items** view would not work once 5,000 items was exceeded.

The list is very simple, with only three "real" data columns that we use to track incoming emails -- it has a  **From, Title**, and **Received** column (which is an indexed column).

I found a solution to only display items received for the current month and it was working great all of October, right up until we hit 5,000 items.  Now, it returns a blank list.  Strangely, the two other views I created for **Last 30 Days** and **Last 7 Days** do still return results.  Note: the current running tally for October's items is only 825 items.

For my **Current Month** view, I created two *calculated* columns:

**StartOfMonth**: with the formula:  =DATE(YEAR(Received),MONTH(Received),1)    returning a **Date Only** result

**EndOfMonth**: with the formula: =DATE(YEAR(Received),MONTH(Received)+1,1)-1     which also returns a **Date Only** result.

The filters for **Current Month** are:

Show the items when column

**StartOfMonth**

is less than or equal to

**[Today]**

AND

When column

**EndOfMonth**

is greater than or equal to

**[Today]**

As I said, this filter/view for **Current Month** was working perfectly until the list hit 5,000 items.

I do note that the **Last 30 Days** view starts with using the Received (indexed) column where I have

Show the items when column
**Received (indexed)**
is greater than or equal to
**[Today]-30**

So I'm wondering if what I'm using for **Current Month** view isn't working because I'm not filtering based on an indexed column?

Does anyone have any insights on how to remedy this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a simple status column and have new entries set to Active. Then a nightly flow runs to set those items over 40 days old to archive. Not ideal, but it works for this scenario.